# How to find files containing newlines in their names

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find, gnu-findutils

There is so much told about correct handling of file names which [contain weird symbols like newlines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I thought using IFS set to newline would solve the issue in general except obviously for the case if one has a name with newline in it. So as a means of defense script could check at first whether a subtree has at least one file with newline and stop with a message to fix the name first.
Surprisingly I couldn't make `find` doing that with `-regex` match. Only way successful was a rather ugly

```
find . -name "*"$'\n'"*"
```

But for example `find . -regex ".*\n.*"` does not work. Emacs regex should allow escape characters like \n, shouldn't it ? Interestingly that it matches another file with character `n` in the name. Experimented with different -regextypes only to find that types `awk` `sed` `posix-extended` and some more would match file with a newline (let's say `a\nxxx`) but in addition they will match files with character `n` as well. Weird.
On other hand GNU find documentation does not tell anything about support of escaped characters like `\n`. Are they really not supported so we can't use `\t \n \r \a` and similar in find regexps ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find all file and directories that have new line in them, you can use this POSIX-compatible call to `find`:

```
find . -name '*
*'
```

where a literal newline is embedded in the single quotes. `bash` supports additional syntax to specify a newline:

```
find . -name \*$'\n'\*
```

OR little less clumsy:

```
EOL=$'\n'
find . -name "*$EOL*"
```

Or using `-regex`:

```
find . -regex ".*$EOL.*"
```

Comment: Indeed, that would work. But would something similar be possible with find -regex test ? So far seems it is not, but thanks anyway.

Comment: +1 I added a POSIX-compatible version, since it didn't seem worth adding a competing answer for such a minor difference.